Npm is not starting 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"'
Please suggest below error for npm start
PS C:\JsonServerSetup> npm start

start
json-server --watch db.json --port 8000

npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm error path C:\JsonServerSetup
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs ENOENT
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\mk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-05-03T08_13_26_164Z-debug-0.log

NPM version is showing in VS code but in cmd is showing error.
PS C:\JsonServerSetup> npm -v
10.7.0
CMD >>>>>>>
C:\Users\mk>npm -v
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.7.0

I change the power shall policy restricted to remotesigned also
Environment variable setup
user variable
user variable path
system variable path
